# Getting uploaded images to upload side by side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a form where users can upload photos and before the form is submitted the selected photos are previewed.

Currently, they don't aline, but how do I get them to display 3 in a line no matter how many are uploaded. So if 5 are uploaded there's 3 photos on row 1, and 2 on row 2.

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card card-default">
            <div class="card-header">Advertise Your Property</div>


            <div class="card-body">
                <form method="POST" action="/createadvert" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="photo" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Images</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                          <input type="file" name="photo" id="myFile" multiple />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">

                          <div class="form-group row previews">

                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <script>
                      /*=============== Script to preview image in upload form ==============*/

                      $("#myFile").change(function(event) {
                        var $previews = $(".previews").empty();
                        [].forEach.call(this.files, function(file) {
                          var reader = new FileReader();
                          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                          reader.onloadend = function() {
                            $previews.append(`<div class="col-4"><img src="${this.result}" class="img-fluid"/></div>`);

                          };
                        });
                      });
                      </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're wrapping the photos in `col-md-12`, but this won't work. You need to place the images directly in the `row`. Change the code to this.

```
      <div class="form-group row previews">
        <!-- photos dynamically inserted here-->
      </div>
```

Then change, the inserted image to this:

```
$previews.append(`<div class="col-4"><img src="${this.result}" class="img-fluid"/></div>`);
```

Comment: Perfect. One more query. They currently display really small. How do i solve this. Here is a sample => https://imgur.com/a/uBECH

Comment: I will, but do you know how  to solved the new query?

Comment: This is everything above form group <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card card-default">
                <div class="card-header">Advertise Your Property</div>
         

                <div class="card-body">

Comment: what version of Bootstrap 4 (specifically)? There is no `card-default` in Bootstrap 4.0.0. and what is the `container` inside?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> is the cdn im using

Comment: Can you delete the unnecessary comments (hover over and is will reveal the X)? What is container inside? Is it in a modal or directly in html>body?

Comment: Directly in the body. I will be post the code in the main section now

Comment: I don't see a reason why the images are small. Maybe you should use something wider that col-md-8, and use container-fluid instead of container.